# How to print numbers read from a binary file in lua?

Tags: lua

I have a binary file and I want to read its contents with lua. I know that it contains float numbers represented as 4 bytes with no delimeters between them. So I open the file and do `t=file:read(4)`. Now I want to print the non-binary representation of the number, but if I do `print(t)`, I only get sth like x98xC1x86. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Lua 5.3, try this code:

```
t=file:read(4)
t=string.unpack(t,"f")
print(t)
```

The library function `string.unpack` converts binary data to Lua types.

Comment: I am using this in torch, which comes with lua 5.2. So, is there any alternative?

Comment: You can use [Robertos struct library](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/) to get the same functionality in older versions of Lua.

Comment: Also my own [lpack](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#lpack).